# How to Manage the setState of multiple widgets. Changing the set state of one widget changes all

Tags: flutter

There are 2 containers and upon pressing one should change the color. but upon selection, it changes both the container's color.

Comment: Sounds like you need to either move the states to each container, so they have their own state or have an object as state, with unique keys per Container.

Comment: Actually i am new to flutter, how to deal with creating an object as state and unique keys?

Comment: I'll make an example as answer. Just gimme a sec

Comment: Thank you so much! It would really help a lot to me

Comment: Please post your code also.So that we will try to understand fix the issue

Comment: Hope you get the idea of how you could solve your problem. If not, please post some more code @SrivatsanNarasimhan

Answer (score 1):

### To have a map with colors

```
class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  Map<String, Color> activeColors;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    activeColors = {
      "container1": Colors.green,
      "container2": Colors.red,
    };
  }

  void changeColorContainer1() {
    setState(() {
      activeColors["container1"] = activeColors["container1"] == Colors.green
          ? Colors.red
          : Colors.green;
    });
  }
  
  void changeColorContainer2() {
    setState(() {
      activeColors["container2"] = activeColors["container2"] == Colors.red
          ? Colors.green
          : Colors.red;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: activeColors["container1"],
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: changeColorContainer1,
              child: Text('Change color Container 1'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: activeColors["container2"],
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: changeColorContainer2,
              child: Text('Change color Container 2'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### To move the state to child containers

```
class Parent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CustomContainer(),
          CustomContainer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomContainerState createState() => _CustomContainerState();
}

class _CustomContainerState extends State<CustomContainer> {
  Color currentColor;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentColor = Colors.green;
  }
  
  void changeColor() {
    setState(() {
      currentColor = currentColor == Colors.green ? Colors.red : Colors.green;
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: currentColor,
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: changeColor,
        child: Text('Change my color'),
      )
    );
  }
}
```